# How could I know which "TextView" is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio

I was creating a dynamic Text View and I need to know which one of those Text views was clicked by the user i read that i need to use getTag() method but it keeps return null when i try it this is my activity code in java:

```
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        TextView temp = new TextView(this);
        temp.setId(i);
        temp.setId(i);
        String s = "";
        temp.setText(s);
        temp.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        mylieniarlayout.addView(temp);
        tv[i] = temp;
    }
    final TextView answertv = findViewById(R.id.answertv);
    mylieniarlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ID: "+ v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            answertv.setText("Clicked ID: " + v.getTag());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, setTag() and getTag() methods on view are not used for identifying the view. We use getId() for identifying the view. Please read document here,
[getTag on android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getTag())

Secondly, your onClickListner is on layout which won't give you the selected id of textView. In your code you are setting an ID for the text view and trying to fetch a tag which is a mistake.

1. onClickListener should be on the textview of which you want a tag.
2. While creating a textView set the tag and then you will get the tag for that textview.

Comment: `setTag()` and `getTag()` can absolutely be used for identifying views, but you need to set the tag to do that.  Otherwise, you're correct, I think the asker is in fact looking for `getId()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `if` `else` condition

Like:

```
if(v.getTag() == 0){
  //Show position 0 here
} else {
  //Other position
}
```

Hope you got your answer